# One anonymous method call in another method in php

Tags: php, anonymous-function, anonymous-methods

I have a problem in calling an anonymous method in another anonymous method.

```
<?php
    $x = function($a)
    {
        return $a;
    };
    $y = function()
    {
        $b = $x("hello world a");
        echo $b;
    };
    $y(); 
?>
```

Error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: x in C:\xampp\htdocs\tsta.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\tsta.php on line 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `use` to your `$y` function, then scope of `$y` function will see `$x` variable:

```
$y = function() use ($x){
    $b = $x("hello world a");
    echo $b;
};
```

Comment: Thanks @arbogast, but if in $y returns several no. of arrays but i want access only particular array how to do that? for example:var_dump($y); and output is : object(Closure)#3 (2) { ["static"]=> array(3) { ["a"]=> &array(2) { ["foc"]=>int(2),["roc"]=>int(4)} ["c"]=> &array(2) { ["foc"]=>int(2),["roc"]=>int(4)} ["a"]=> &array(2) { ["foc"]=>int(2),["roc"]=>int(4)}   i access array 'b' in my case.   i hope you can understand. Thanks

Comment: @Albertestein I don't fully understand you. In your example function $y doesn't return anything, there is no return statement so it is returning NULL by default.

Comment: Sorry brother i have doing some changes in code i mention that.<?php

$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

$x = function($a) use ($arr){
$tst = $arr[$a];
return $tst;
};

$y = function() use($x){
$b = $x(2);
//echo $b;
};

$y(); 

var_dump($y); Output:object(Closure)#2 (1) { ["static"]=> array(1) { ["x"]=> object(Closure)#1 (2) { ["static"]=> array(1) { ["arr"]=> array(6) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(4) [4]=> int(5) [5]=> int(6) } } ["parameter"]=> array(1) { ["$a"]=> string(10) "" } } } } ...

Comment: @Albertestein Still I don't follow you. You are accesing in function `$y` array element `$arr[2]` which has value `3` and what more do you want? Maybe write new question with your full code and write there precisely what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Both @argobast and @hiren-raiyani answers are valid. The most generic one is the first, but the latter is more appropriate if the only consumer of the first anonymous function is the second one (ie $x is used only by $y).

Another option is (this one needs a change in the signature of the $y function) is to pass the anon. function as an argument to the function:

```
<?php

$x = function($a) 
{
    return $a;
};

$y = function(Closure $x)
{
    $b = $x('hello world a');
    echo $b;
};

$y($x);
```

This kind of "dependency injection" seems a bit cleaner to me instead of having a hidden dependency on $x with a 'use', but the choice is up to you.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use anonymous function in same block.

```
<?php

$y = function(){
    $x = function($a){
        return  $a;
    };
    $b = $x("hello world a");
    echo $b;
};
$y();
```

Good Luck!!